# How do static analysis tools automate separation logic?

Tags: software-verification, smt-solvers

I understand separation logic as a form of verification method, similar to Hoare logic. That is, they allow to reason about statements of the form $\{P\} C \{Q\}$, where $C$ is an instruction, and $P$ is pre-condition, $Q$ a post-condition.

My question is: How is separation logic used in practice? Do we *manually* derive some of sort of instantiation of the set of states that could fulfill $P$ and $Q$ or do we use SMT solvers in practice? If so, how are the SMT solvers used? Do we need (via bi-abduction)